# Create a new datatable from the inbuilt dataTable filter in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a dataTable to show a table in `shiny`. I would like the user to be able to type in a search term in to the inbuilt datatable filter box and for the results of this to be stored in a new datatable. How can this be done? Can anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look at package DT https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

You want to get the reactive value from section 2.2 (on the link)

> input$tableId_rows_all: the indices of rows on all pages (after the
>   table is filtered by the search strings)